# How can I move the cursor to the top or bottom of the screen?

Tags: cursor-movement

I know that `gg` and `G` can move the cursor to the top and bottom of the file. But is there a way to jump to the top or bottom of the visible window?

Comment: Capital H does not work for me. I'm using Linux ubuntuxfr 5.4.0-77-generic #86~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 18 01:23:22 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux i can only get the cursor within 5 or sometimes 6 lines from the top of the window ( unless i'm editing one of the very first lines in the file ). Other distros i've used in the past did not have this issue. thoughts ?

Comment: @ochoa your "Answer" was not an answer to the question. We use those only to provide an answer to the original question. If you have a question, you may follow up with a comment to clarify something _or_ ask a new question. See also [ask],[answer].

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Type <kbd>H</kbd> (capital H, H for "high") to move to the top of the screen.

Type <kbd>M</kbd> (capital M, M for "middle") to move to the middle of the screen.

Type <kbd>L</kbd> (capital L, L for "low") to move to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Since `j` moves down and `k` moves up, it's a little awkward that `J` and `K` don't make these top/bottom movements.  Is there a mnemonic to remember these by, similar to `M` for "middle" like @Caco points out?

Comment: @user1717828 H for High, L for Low.

Comment: mnemonic
H high -- top
L low -- bottom

Comment: @Marcio I also edited the answer to include the mnemonics, since you were not the only one to comment on it... Thanks for your contribution and welcome to the site!